# Web application cannot start. Ruby On rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu

I got an issue with starting Ruby application.
I got Ubuntu 14.04,  Apache/2.4.7, ruby 2.2.5p319 and some Web Apllication installed on. 
When I try to go to application page, i see the exception and a trace in my browser.

```
      Web application could not be started

        cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:245:in     
        `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
        /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:348:in 
        `running_bundler'
        /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:243:in 
        `run_load_path_setup_code'
        /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
        /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `'
        /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in 
        `'
        /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in
```

Also environmet variables:

```
    APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
    SHELL = /bin/bash
    APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
    PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXybOMMs
    USER = appuser
    APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
    PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    PWD = /var/app
    APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
    LANG = C
    NODE_PATH = /usr/share/passenger/node
    SHLVL = 0
    HOME = /home/appuser
    LOGNAME = appuser
    APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
    APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
    IN_PASSENGER = 1
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
    RAILS_ENV = production
    RACK_ENV = production
    WSGI_ENV = production
    NODE_ENV = production
    PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
    SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
    SERVER_ADDR = x.x.x.x
    REMOTE_ADDR = y.y.y.y
    REQUEST_URI = /
    SSL_TLS_SNI = myaddr.com
    HTTPS = on
    SERVER_PORT = 443
    SERVER_NAME = myaddr.com
    SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
    SERVER_ADMIN = youremail@example.com
    REMOTE_PORT = 51589
    DOCUMENT_ROOT = /var/myapp/public
    QUERY_STRING = 
    REQUEST_METHOD = GET
```

```
    RUBY_VERSION = 2.2.6
    RUBY_PLATFORM = i386-linux-gnu
    RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
    RubyGems version = 2.4.5.2
```

It seems that some parts of Ruby's previous version still has influence to the WebApp, but I can't find where to correct it.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any gems installed on that server? Is `bundler` available? Did you run `bundle install` on that server? How do you deploy your application, with `capistrano`?

Comment: Yes, I ran 'bundle install' many times. The software (Canvas Learning management system) was installed directly from Github.

Comment: @AntonAtamanov: Try this `gem install bundler`

Comment: There is no effect..